# Почему элемент контейнера меняет свое положение в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему элементы контейнера меняю свое положение при данном коде:

```
 this.container = document.querySelector(container);
    this.slides = this.container.children;
```

Это 2 переменные, проблема в том что, есть кнопка вперед в слайдере, и при нажатие вызывается код ниже, где контейнер - это обертка слайдера, а слайды - это сами элементы. При нажатии, у меня слайд на первом месте становится на последнее, но я не могу понять

```
this.container.append(this.slides[0]);
```

почему 1 элемент исчезает и появляется в конце, мы же его не не удаляем. Как по мне, тоже самое что и

```
 let arr = [1,2,3,5];
        arr[arr.length] = arr[0];
```

где мы получаем массив и в конец ставим значение 1 элемента и в конце получаем массив `1 2 3 5 1`.

Почему так же не работает с моей проблемой?

Comment: так работает `.append` - он берет элемент и вставляет его в конец. Один элемент не может находится одновременно и спереди и сзади, поэтому вначале ты его и не видишь

Comment: @Grundy, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, надо дубликат поискать, что-то такое было уже